# Haskell extremely slow simple recurrence

Tags: python, haskell, profiling, tail-recursion

I'm experimenting with `Haskell` profiling with a simple recursive `max` algorithm:

```
max_tag :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
max_tag head [] = head
max_tag head (x:xs) =
    let {m = max_tag x xs} in
      let {b = (Prelude.<=) m head} in
        case b of {True -> head; False -> m}
```

When I compare it to a python imperative equivalent, I get a **10x speed factor** in favor of python:

```
with open("input.txt") as fl:
    data = [int(d) for d in fl.read().splitlines()]
max_ = 0
for d in data:
    if max_ < d:
        max_ = d
print(max_)
```

- It seems there is an *inherent limitation* of using *tail recursion* in the `Haskell` case, am I right?
- Any *other* way to make the Haskell code faster?
- The input file contains `1M` unsigned, unbounded integers (on average 32 digits)

For completeness, here is the complete `Haskell` file (not sure it is needed):

```
import Max
import System.IO  
import Control.Monad
import System.Environment
import Prelude

readInt :: String -> Integer
readInt = read

max_tag :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
max_tag head [] = head
max_tag head (x:xs) =
    let {m = max_tag x xs} in
      let {b = (Prelude.<=) m head} in
        case b of {True -> head; False -> m}

main = do
    args <- getArgs
    contents <- readFile "input.txt"
    let numbers_as_strings = words $ contents
    let numbers = map readInt numbers_as_strings
    let max_number = max_tag 0 numbers
    print max_number
```

**EDIT**:
refactor suggested by @Willem Van Onsem,
works ! (28 sec -> 12 sec)

```
max_bar :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
max_bar head [] = head
max_bar head (x:xs) =
  let {b = head < x} in
    let {m = case b of {True -> x; False -> head}} in
      max_bar m xs
```

Any ideas on further improvements? I must be faster than python !

Comment: What about using `maximum`?

Comment: This is by the way not tail recursion, since you will first recurse and *then* have extra work to decide what the maximum is of the two. For tail recursion, you use the accumulator.

Comment: I want to compare hand written simple functions, not library functions

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem exactly, I think there is NO way to make this code use tail recursion because of the reason you wrote ...

Comment: The bottleneck here is likely I/O. Strings can be extremely slow compared to Data.Text or Data.ByteString. I would suggest measuring the time taken by the I/O and the function separately first.

Comment: @OrenlshShalom: what about `max_tag head (x:xs) = max_tag (max head x) xs`?

Comment: But as Dogbert says, `String`s are *not* a good way to parse huge amounts of data in Haskell: this is implemented as a linked list, and thus often has a lot of overhead when parsing a sequence of characters.

Comment: @Dogbert I did, the loading time was very fast

Comment: @OrenIshShalom can you try comparing the time taken by your function vs time taken to print the `length` of the input? Note that `readFile` will produce a lazy string which will be incrementally evaluated as you first use it.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom: notice that processing is lazy, so the parsing to the `Integer`s is not per se done, since the interpreter doesn't has a reason to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this to benchmark your function should make it go much faster (also be sure to use `text` version 2.0 or later):

```hs
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as T
import qualified Data.Text.Read as T

readInt :: T.Text -> Integer
readInt t = 
  case T.signed T.decimal t of
    Right (x, _) -> x

main :: IO ()
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    contents <- T.readFile "input.txt"
    let numbers_as_strings = T.words contents
    let numbers = map readInt numbers_as_strings
    let max_number = max_tag 0 numbers
    print max_number
```

You can also speed up your `max_tag` function itself by making it tail recursive and thus avoiding a bunch of memory allocations:

```hs
max_tag :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
max_tag head [] = head
max_tag head (x:xs) 
  | x <= head = max_tag head xs
  | otherwise = max_tag x xs
```

You can make it even slightly faster by using `foldr` so that you get foldr/build fusion with `map readInt`:

```hs
max_tag :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
max_tag x0 xs = foldr (\x go y -> if x > y then go x else go y) id xs x0
```

Comment: I get a syntax error with the `|` writing style

Comment: @OrenIshShalom then there must be something wrong in the way you copied it or in your setup somewhere. This is legal Haskell syntax.

Comment: Ooops you're completely right !

Comment: Thanks it works ! now I have 3.6 sec vs 2.8 on python - good enough for me :)

Answer (score 4):

An even more efficient way than @Noughtmare's answer is to use `Data.ByteString` which does not have the overhead of handling encodings, which is not needed here. In my tests, with one million random 32 digit numbers as input, this runs in ~290ms while the answer by @Noughtmare runs in ~1020ms. For comparison, the original Python one runs in ~560ms.

```hs
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import Data.Maybe (fromJust)

-- NOTE: This will throw an error if parsing fails.
readInt :: B.ByteString -> Integer
readInt = fst . fromJust . C.readInteger

main :: IO ()
main = do
  contents <- B.readFile "read-integers.txt"
  let numbers = map readInt $ C.lines contents
  print $ max_tag 0 numbers

max_tag :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
max_tag head [] = head
max_tag head (x : xs) = max_tag (max head x) xs
```