# Contest problem: TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED for Haskell solution

Tags: performance, haskell, memory

I'm trying to solve this problem https://codeforces.com/contest/285/problem/C?locale=en. On test #7 I have got TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED (the limit is 1000ms). How can I optimize my solution?

```
import Data.List
import Data.Int

(|>) a b = b a

main = do
    s1 <- getLine
    s2 <- getLine
    let n = s1 |> (read :: String -> Int64)
        a = s2 |> words |> map (read :: String -> Int64)
        r = sort a |> zipWith (\x y -> abs (x - y)) [1 .. n] |> sum
    print r
```

Test output:

```
Test: #7, time: 1000 ms., memory: 98516 KB, exit code: -1, checker exit code: 0, verdict: TIME_LIMIT_EXCEEDED

Input
300000
299996 65 64 63 62 61 60 59 58 70 53 79 88 97 106 115 124 133 142 45 151 160 169 178 187 196 ...
```

Comment: Can you try switching to ByteString based I/O if that's the bottleneck here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72521874

Comment: @Dogbert All 33 tests are passed, max time 810ms. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to switch to ByteString based I/O as suggested by Dogbert.

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List
import qualified Data.ByteString as B
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

-- NOTE: This will throw an error if parsing fails.
readInt :: B.ByteString -> Integer
readInt = fst . fromJust . C.readInteger

(|>) a b = b a

main = do
    s1 <- B.getLine
    s2 <- B.getLine
    let n = s1 |> readInt
        a = s2 |> C.words |> map readInt
        r = sort a |> zipWith (\x y -> abs (x - y)) [1 .. n] |> sum
    print r
```